# Array appending overwrites last index of Realm object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, append, realm

I have an array of Realm objects and before i save them in Realm DB i have my own array of objects in for loop:

```
var objs = [self.friendsObject] //0 values at first
for i in (0..<json.count) { //counts 2

  let _id = json[i]["_id"] as? String
  let userName = json[i]["userName"] as? String
  let profile_pic = json[i]["profile_pic"] as? String
  let phone = json[i]["phone"] as? String

  self.friendsObject.id = _id!
  self.friendsObject.username = userName!
  self.friendsObject.profilepic = profile_pic!
  self.friendsObject.phone = phone!

  objs.append(self.friendsObject) //2nd element overwrites 1st one
  }
self.friendsObject.save(objects: objs)
```

So i can see the first object with correct items inside `objs` before i insert second array, but in second index there are 2 array of objects with same values. i appreciate any help.

**Note:** It is not duplicate, i have already checked some similar questions but it doesn't apply to my issue.

Comment: It **is** a duplicate, I answered this kind of question a couple of times. You are using always the same object (`self.friendsObject`), you are appending the same object in the loop and due to reference semantics all properties are updated in all occurrences of the item simultaneously. Actually they are not updated simultaneously, it's still **one** object all occurrences are referring to.

Comment: Then should i initialise my array as var `objs = [AnyObject]()` or something ?

Comment: I have no idea what `objs` is, anyway you have to initialize / create a new instance **inside** the loop.

Comment: @Umitk Jack's comment is offtopic / not related to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vadian commented, the problem is that the code is not creating new instances of `friendsObject` but appending the same instance with different values.

**Edit**

Below an example of how to copy JSON to a class based on the information provided in the question:

```
    // Simulating a JSON structure filled with some data.
    var jsonData = [Int: [String: String]]()

    for index in 0..<10 {
        var values = [String: String]()
        values["id"] = "id\(index)"
        values["username"] = "username\(index)"
        values["profilepic"] = "profilepic\(index)"
        values["phone"] = "phone\(index)"
        jsonData[index] = values
    }

    // Friend sample class where JSON data will be copied to.
    class Friend {

        var id: String
        var username: String
        var profilepic: String
        var phone: String

        init(_ id: String, _ username: String, _ profilepic: String, _ phone: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.username = username
            self.profilepic = profilepic
            self.phone = phone
        }
    }

    // The array where to copy the values from the JSON data.
    var friends = [Friend]()

    // Looping through the JSON data with a sorted key.
    for jsonSortedKey in jsonData.keys.sorted(by: <) {

        // Obtaining a JSON element containing friend data.
        let jsonFriend = jsonData[jsonSortedKey]!

        // Creating a new friend's instance from the JSON friend's data.
        let friend = Friend((jsonFriend["id"]!), jsonFriend["username"]!, (jsonFriend["profilepic"]!),  (jsonFriend["phone"]!))

        friends.append(friend)
    }
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: I have done some changes, but then it will owerwrite first object. Can you give me some code examples for better understanding?

Comment: @Umitk Please first read https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 until you understand exactly what reference semantics are. Next, instead of using the same `self.friendsObject` each time your loop iterates, instantiate a new `FriendsObject`, set the values on that, and then append that new object to your array. (Since you didn't provide the definition for whatever type `self.friendsObject` is, I'm guessing at what you're trying to achieve; you may need to modify my advice depending on exactly how your class works.)